# FUNF probe configurable fields

Tags: android

I am working on an application which is based on FUNF sensing framework. http://www.funf.org/

I want to create general settings activity for every probe. How can I get configurable fields for the probe? I need their name and data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me answer my own question, since nobody cares about FUNF. :)

I found this way of getting the configurable fields for the probe.

```
List<Field> configurableFields = AnnotationUtil.getAllFieldsWithAnnotation(new ArrayList<Field>(), MyProbe.class, Configurable.class);
```